# Maclaurin series for $\frac{\cos2x-1}{x^2}$ using Maclaurin series for $\cos2x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am having some trouble finding the first three nonzero terms for the maclaurin series of $\frac{\cos2x-1}{x^2}$ using the maclaurin series for $\cos2x$.

So far I have the maclaurin series for $\cos2x$ being:
$$\cos2x=1-\frac{4x^2}{2!} + \frac{16x^4}{4!} - \frac{64x^6}{6!}\dots$$
However I am not sure how to proceed in finding the macluarin series for $\frac{\cos2x-1}{x^2}$ now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maclaurin series can be treated as infinite polynomials (most of the time), so we have
$$\cos2x-1=- \frac{4x^2}{2!} + \frac{16x^4}{4!} - \frac{64x^6}{6!}+\dots$$
$$\frac{\cos2x-1}{x^2}=- \frac{4}{2!} + \frac{16x^2}{4!} - \frac{64x^4}{6!}+\dots$$
$$=-2+\frac23x^2-\frac4{45}x^4+\dots$$

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, you divided the maclaurin series of $cos(2x)-1$ by $\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: @Ludwig Yes, after subtracting $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since \begin{eqnarray}
\cos(2x) = 1 - \frac{4x^2}{2!} + \frac{16x^4}{4!} - \frac{64x^6}{6!} \cdots
\end{eqnarray}
$$\cos (2x) -  1 = \frac{4x^2}{2!} + \frac{16x^4}{4!} - \frac{64x^6}{6!} \cdots$$
$$\frac{\cos(2x)-1}{x^2} = \frac{4}{2!} + \frac{16x^2}{4!} - \frac{64x^4}{6!} \cdots$$
$$=\boxed{2 + \frac{16x^2}{4!} - \frac{64x^4}{6!} \cdots}$$